# How to prevent special characters in MVC4 model property

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model that contains a "Name" property.

I want to block some of the special characters that are not allowed. 
These are the special characters which I want to dis-allow:

<> {} []

I have used this code:

```
 [Required]
 [RegularExpression("^[^<>{}[]]")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

but it doesn't work. It's always showing this message:

```
The field Name must match the regular expression '^[^<>{}[]]'.
```

Please help

Comment: Try using `[^<>{}[]]*` as regular expression.

Comment: I have tried this but its not working

Comment: I want that only these character <> {} [] does not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your regex:

- You must escape square brackets to match literal brackets
- Your regex matches only the first character of the string. The rest of the string could be any characters and still match.

Try this:

`^[^<>{}\[\]]+$`

Comment: Thanks Brian for Updating and answering my question. It's working fine for now,